# Which firewall port required to access python repository?

Tags: linux, firewall, redhat, linux-networking, python

Trying to install python library from corporate Server. Due to security reason the internet is blocked and specific URL's only allowed.

So would like to raise a firewall opening to install python lib using pip install. Do anyone know which ports are required to access library using pip ? or any other better solution to handle this ?

I made a firewall opening to Port:80 and 443 for the URL:https://pypi.org/ and its not working.

```
pip install https://pypi.org/project/paramiko/

Collecting https://pypi.org/project/paramiko/
  Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None)) after connection broken by 'ConnectTimeoutError(<pip._vendor.requests.packages.urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x7fa40ff24828>, 'Connection to pypi.org timed out. (connect timeout=15)')': /project/paramiko/
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

https://pypi.org/project/paramiko/ - communicates only via 443 port, but for installation the following URI is used - https://api.github.com/repos/paramiko/paramiko
Check, if it is blocked by firewall

EDIT: screenshot for second lib as asked
[image]

Comment: Ok, I gave an example. Even if i use anyother lib https://pypi.org/project/PyNaCl/ still getting same error messages. Is something wrong in firewall opening ? based on your answer i understand we cant access all lib in pypi.org.

Comment: I added a screenshot regarding another lib.

Comment: Can you open in (lynx) browser the following URI: 
https://pypi.org/project/paramiko/
and
https://api.github.com/repos/paramiko/paramiko

Comment: Thanks, Its due to wrong url given  to open firewall pypi.python.org. After adding pypi.org  & files.pythonhosted.org on 443 worked.